# How to make my contract balance as private in Ethereum?

Tags: solidity, balances, solidity-0.5.x

Suppose there are two contracts, `A` and `B`. Obviously, balance of `A` is public and `B` can read it with `address_of_A.balance`. Is there a way to make balance of `A` as a private data and `B` can't read it with the mentioned command?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: That is not possible

Comment: Impossible at the moment

Answer (score -1):

The balance of ERC-20 contracts are public because the [Ethereum ERC20 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) is described the balanceOf function as public

The event history recorded in Ethereum can always be read but you can make it difficult for the contract B, for example like this:

```
function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns (uint256) {
    if(msg.sender == address_of_B){ return 0; }
    return balances[owner];
}
```

or

```
function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns (uint256) {
    require(msg.sender != address_of_B);
    return balances[owner];
}
```

Comment: I want to make balance as a private such that `B` can't reached it via `,address_of_A>.balance`. By this command `B` doesn't need to call any function from `A` contract and just need to run the built-in method `.balance`.

Comment: "Thank you" for the negative vote. I am only tried to help with the impossible goal of changing the rules of the blockchain XD